# Linux Hash Command Searching

Tags: linux, shell

I came across the [pyspark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/pyspark#L51) code and there is a function that really confused me.

```
if hash python2.7 2>/dev/null; then
  # Attempt to use Python 2.7, if installed:
  DEFAULT_PYTHON="python2.7"
else
  DEFAULT_PYTHON="python"
fi
```

The comment was saying "# Determine the Python executable to use if PYSPARK_PYTHON or PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON isn't set:
", but I have only used hash to find the frequency of recently used shell commands, I really don't know how this is working.

Can anyone help me understand this if statement?

Comment: You've used hash to do what? Do you mean `history` and `uniq`? The `hash` command is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-hash).

Comment: I am not certain where your question is at. Seems like it's not about `hash` at all (you might need to edit question title), but that `if` doesn't look like common `if [[ ... ]]`. If that's the question, then just run `help if` in Bash and read it.

Comment: @livibetter : `if cmd ; then echo worked ; else echo nope ;fi` is a common idiom for testing the exit status of a `cmd`. To see it work, try substituting `/bin/true` or `/bin/false` for `cmd` in my sample. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter did you mean to @ B.Mr..W.?

Answer (score 0):

from [here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hash.htm), hash will search $PATH if a name is provided.